# Find sed grep insert and replace on OSX

Tags: sed, grep, find

I have a load of files that I need to edit and they look like this:

```
[COURSE HEADER]
VERSION = 0
UNITS = ENGLISH
DESCRIPTION = workout #19
FILE NAME = none
MINUTES FTP
[END COURSE HEADER]
...
```

I need to do a few manipulation on these file (they are all located in the same folder), first the version has to be updated from 0 to 2, file name should be replaced with the real file name of the current file being processed, I need to insert a new line that contains "FTP=100" and I need to replace the word FTP from this line "MINUTES  FTP" (`MINUTES<tab>FTP`).

So it should look like this:

```
[COURSE HEADER]
VERSION = 2
UNITS = ENGLISH
DESCRIPTION = workout #19
FILE NAME = workout19.erg
FTP=100
MINUTES  WATTS
[END COURSE HEADER]
...
```

Comment: You could also consider using python with config parser module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to you have all the files in the same folder, you can do it with a simple `for` loop, and `sed`ing each file using multiple commads (with [`-e` option](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html)) in a single line:

```
for FILE in *; do
    sed -i.bak -e "s_\(VERSION = \)0_\12_" -e "/FILE NAME = none/{
        r"<(echo "FILE NAME = $FILE"; echo FTP=100)"
        d
    }" -e "s_\(MINUTES\)\tFTP_\1\tWATTS_" "$FILE"
done
```

here `sed` is executing three replacements per line:

- `s_\(VERSION = \)0_\12_`
- `"/FILE NAME = none/{
      r"<(echo "FILE NAME = $FILE"; echo FTP=100)"
      d
  }"`
- `s_\(MINUTES\)\tFTP_\1\tWATTS_`

Notice the use of [Backreferences](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html#uh-10) (`\(...\)`) to remember the patterns. In the first command, `\12` means the backreference `\1` followed by the char `2` (remembered patterns go from **0** through **9**).

In the second sentence, I think the best way to avoid bad interpretation of the characters `$FILE` could contain, is to make a [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) to be read by the [`r` command](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-37) and delete the old pattern with [`d` command](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-30).

---

#### Example

```
$ cat Centennial\ T90-TSS107IF0.84.ergn 
[COURSE HEADER]
VERSION = 0
UNITS = ENGLISH
DESCRIPTION = 20 Minute Test,90,80.
FILE NAME = none
MINUTES FTP
[END COURSE HEADER]

[COURSE DATA]
0   40
10  65
10  100
11  100
11  65
12  65
12  105
13  105
13  65
14  65
14  110
15  110
15  65
20  65
20  90
20.5    110
20.5    110
25  110
25  50
30  50
30  95
32  107
32  107
50  107
50  30
55  50
55  50
60  30
[END COURSE DATA]

$ for FILE in *; do
>     sed -e "s_\(VERSION = \)0_\12_" -e "/FILE NAME = none/{
>         r"<(echo "FILE NAME = $FILE"; echo FTP=100)"
>         d
>     }" -e "s_\(MINUTES\)\tFTP_\1\tWATTS_" "$FILE"
> done
[COURSE HEADER]
VERSION = 2
UNITS = ENGLISH
DESCRIPTION = 20 Minute Test,90,80.
FILE NAME = Centennial T90-TSS107IF0.84.ergn
FTP=100
MINUTES WATTS
[END COURSE HEADER]

[COURSE DATA]
0   40
10  65
10  100
11  100
11  65
12  65
12  105
13  105
13  65
14  65
14  110
15  110
15  65
20  65
20  90
20.5    110
20.5    110
25  110
25  50
30  50
30  95
32  107
32  107
50  107
50  30
55  50
55  50
60  30
[END COURSE DATA]
```

Comment: I'm using the stock bash version 10.10.1

Comment: File name and FTP=100 is now fixed but -e "s_\(MINUTES\) FTP_\1  WATTS_" is still not being replaced and it doesn't generate any error. Just a confirmation, the space between MINUTES_TAB_FTP is a TAB.

Comment: In that case just replace the space with `\t`. See my updated answer.

Comment: :( nope that's still not working. Here is a [link](http://charetx2.com/20_Minute_Test_V60-TSS80IF0.9.erg) to the file if that could help.

Comment: I've just added an example, it works for me. Maybe some blank characters we don see. You can try replacing `\t` with `[\t ]*`. Sorry I can't help you further.

Comment: Thank you, you have been great help, truly appreciated :)